# A better, more-succinct, pattern to validate in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a better way to write this pattern of setting a variable and checking it's value after a loop?

```
<?php

$isValid = false;
foreach ($posts as $post) {

    // If post ID matches the request ID
    if($post->id == $id) {

        $isValid = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!$isValid) {

    // Not valid!
    header('Location: ...');
}
```

It seems there would be a better way of writing this.

Comment: if $posts was just an array of ids, then it'd be a simple `if(in_array($posts, $id))`, but since it's a multidimensional construct, that won't work, and you're stuck with looping.

Comment: ^ you could cast it, but I would just stick with looping :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!array_filter($posts, function ($post) use ($id) { return $post->id == $id; })) {
    header(...);
}
```

(Optionally assign that long-liner into a variable first to make it more readable.)

If you're partial to [Functional PHP](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php):

```
if (F\none($posts, function ($post) use ($id) { return $post->id == $id; })) {
    header(...);
}
```

Not a big difference, but reads better.

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this to make it shorter, but that is about it...

```
<?php
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    // If post ID matches the request ID
    if($post->id != $id) {
        header("Location: ...");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: That'll abort on the first unmatched id, which is NOT what the OP wants. OP's looking to see if there's at least ONE matched ip, in which case DON'T redirect.